# Отрисовать таблицу

Tags: php, html, ооп, mvc, zend2

Добрый день. Не могу понять как отрисовать таблицу. У меня есть вью часть, контроллер, модель и класс, который обрабатывает некие данные и отрисовывает таблицу, но как сделать так, чтобы таблица отрисовалась в контроллере я не пойму вот классы
модель

```
<?php
namespace Application\Models;

class SiteAdressModel {
    private $firstAdressPart = "http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=";
    private $secondAdressPart;


    public function __construct($takenDate) {
        $this->secondAdressPart = $takenDate;
    }

    public function getFirstAdressPart() {
        return $this->firstAdressPart;
    }

    public function getSecondAdressPart() {
        return $this->secondAdressPart;
    }
}
```

контроллер

```
<?php


namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

use Application\Models\SiteAdressModel;

use Application\Models\TableCreater;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }
    public function mainAction()
    {
        $adressPart = \htmlspecialchars($_POST['date']);
        $model = new SiteAdressModel($adressPart);
        $tableCreator = new TableCreater($model->getFirstAdressPart(), $model->getSecondAdressPart());
        $tableCreator->createXML();
}
```

обработчик данных из вью

```
<?php

namespace Application\Models;

class TableCreater{

    private $finalAdress;
    private $date;
    private $content;
    private $XML;
    public function __construct($FirstPart, $SecondPart) {
        $this->finalAdress = $FirstPart;
        $this->date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($SecondPart));
        $this->finalAdress .= $this->date;
    }
    public function createXML() {
        $this->content = file_get_contents($this->finalAdress);
        $this->XML = SimpleXMLElement($this->content);
    }
    public function getXML() {
        return $this->XML;
    }
    public function createTable() {
        echo "<table class='table table-striped' border=1>";
        echo "<tr><th>Valute ID</th><th>NumCode</th><th>CharCode</th><th>Nominal</th><th>Name</th><th>Value</th></tr>";
        foreach ($this->XML->Valute as $entry) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo (string) $entry->attributes();
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $entry->NumCode;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $entry->CharCode;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $entry->Nominal;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $entry->Name;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $entry->Value;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }

}
```

и вью, куда идет роуминг и в которой должна отрисоваться таблица.
не дает вставить html-разметку, но там пустая таблица с шапкой, а вот дальше в таблице должны быть данные, как их туда передать, я, увы, понять не могу

Answer (score 3):

Возникает вопрос - почему у тебя отрисовка таблицы у тебя занимается модель \Application\Models\TableCreater ? Отрисовкой таблицы должен заниматься вид. Или же помошник вида изредка. Открой вид module\Application\view\application\index\main.phtml и там рендерь таблицу. Передать параметры в вид в контроллере например можно:

```
$view = new ViewModel();
$view->adress = [$model->getFirstAdressPart(), $model->getSecondAdressPart()]; 
return $view;
```

В виде же, после того как ты сделаешь TableCreater вью-хелпером:

```
$this->tableCreator($this->adress[0], $this->adress[1]);
```

Вместо echo в TableCreater - необходимо заполнять переменную и возвращать её, так затем удобнее использовать хелперы.